# Socket communication between Gears on OpenShift

Tags: java, sockets, openshift

I have 2 DIY Gears running simple a Java Client-Server Application with Sockets.

What I want to do is sent a command via Socket to Gear1, which sends a command via Socket to Gear2, then sends back to the user whatever data Gear2 sent back.
The problem is that I can't connect to Gear2 from Gear1.

Gear1 address = 127.13.55.1:16000
Gear2 address = 127.7.21.129:16001

I forwarded port 16000 on Gear1 so that I can communicate with it from a local client. But when I try to connect to Gear2 from inside Gear1 I get the error message: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host.

Is there some configuration I forgot about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two gears will not be able to communicate with each other on those ports.  Inter-gear communication is blocked on non standard ports, except in special cases with scaled applications.  You would have to use port forwarding between the gears for this to work, the same as you do from your local machine.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Do you know how I can do port-forwarding between the gears?

Comment: You would need to add your private key to your gear and then use the port-forward commands

Comment: Is there any other way to get the two gears to communicate with each other? Port forwarding would need direct intervention from me, I want this to happen automatically, whenever I call a function on Gear1.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use RESTful resources instead of socket connections, or servlets or whatever depending on what language(s) you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I found a blog that says pretty much the same thing: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/intra-gear-instance-communications

Apparently there's no other alternative.